# Grid rows are not expanding to fill window width

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid

On my Wpf window I have a grid with two rows and two columns. The first row is set to span across both columns, and the second row contains two columns.

Here's the code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <fluent:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <!-- Ribbon code here -->
    </fluent:Ribbon>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <local:LeftPane DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <local:RightPane DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here's the output:

[image: my window]
<sub>(source: [unconventionalmommy.com](http://www.unconventionalmommy.com/Gridpic.png))</sub>

Why are these two rows not stretching to fill the space on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O joy -- Found the answer here:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/gridlayout.html

Changed Width from "Auto" to "*"

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
```